# Thread synchronization @ Native Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, linux-kernel, pthreads

Windows CRITICAL_SECTION is implemented in a way lighter than mutex ( as far as for the lock/unlock perf cost ) By utilizing a spinlock and a semaphore to reduce user/kernel switches.

A mutex require a context switch even if the mutex is not currently owned/locked where a CRITICAL_SECTION will req that only after a period of time sinning on the spin lock ( results in better perf ).

I am new to Android Native dev, having in mind windows CRITICAL_SECTION, is there an equivalent in Native Android?

Is there anything lighter than pthread_mutex_*.* @ Android? does 'pthread_mutex_*.*' impose a context switch even if the mutex is not already ~owned/locked~ ( as in windows )?

Having in mind rapid entering/exiting a critical section What is the usage cost of 'pthread_mutex_*.*' impose ?

Is there a user-mode spinlock @ Native Android ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Nadav at Sophin

Comment: do u have any idea about android device lock/unlock at native layer i.e. at c/c++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the `pthread_mutex_lock()` in Android's Bionic libc does *not* impose a context switch for locking a normal mutex in the uncontended state - a simple atomic compare-and-exchange is used, followed by a memory barrier.  Likewise unlocking a mutex does not require a kernel entry if there is no process waiting on it.

You can find the Bionic implementation of `pthread_mutex_lock()` and `pthread_mutex_unlock()` in `libc/bionic/pthread.c` in the Bionic libc sources and see this yourself.

In general you can consider `pthread_mutex_lock()` / `pthread_mutex_unlock()` to be quite lightweight.

Answer (score 3):

following is some encapsulation pthread mutex into windows style CRITICAL_SECTION

```
typedef struct tagCRITICAL_SECTION {
  pthread_mutex_t     _mutex;
  pthread_mutexattr_t _mutexattr;
} CRITICAL_SECTION, *LPCRITICAL_SECTION;


static inline
VOID InitializeCriticalSection(LPCRITICAL_SECTION lpCriticalSection) {
  //  printf("[init]  %0x\n", (UINT)lpCriticalSection);
  int ret;
  ret = pthread_mutexattr_init(&(lpCriticalSection->_mutexattr));
  assert(ret==0);
#if defined (__APPLE__) || defined(__linux__)
    pthread_mutexattr_settype(&lpCriticalSection->_mutexattr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE);
#elif ANDROID
    // Do nothing
#else
  lpCriticalSection->_mutexattr.__mutexkind = PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE_NP;
#endif
  ret = pthread_mutex_init(&(lpCriticalSection->_mutex),
                           &(lpCriticalSection->_mutexattr));
  assert(ret==0);
}

static inline
VOID DeleteCriticalSection    (LPCRITICAL_SECTION lpCriticalSection) {
  int ret;
  ret = pthread_mutex_destroy    (&(lpCriticalSection->_mutex));
  assert(ret==0);
  ret = pthread_mutexattr_destroy(&(lpCriticalSection->_mutexattr));
  assert(ret==0);
}

static inline
VOID EnterCriticalSection     (LPCRITICAL_SECTION lpCriticalSection) {
  int ret;
  ret = pthread_mutex_lock(&(lpCriticalSection)->_mutex);
  assert(ret==0);
}

static inline
BOOL TryEnterCriticalSection     (LPCRITICAL_SECTION lpCriticalSection) {
  int ret;
  ret = pthread_mutex_trylock(&(lpCriticalSection)->_mutex);

  return ret == 0;
}

static inline
VOID LeaveCriticalSection     (LPCRITICAL_SECTION lpCriticalSection) {
  int ret;
  ret = pthread_mutex_unlock(&(lpCriticalSection->_mutex));
  // ret==1 means mutex is owned by another thread!
}
```

Comment: This implementation is quite handy, TnX!!! however, it simply wrap aounf pthread mutex w/o implementing the spinlock logic, Any1 aware of usermode spinlock implementaion ?